# Replacing a Pegatron M2N78-LA MOBO with an ASUS M4A785-M MOBO connector issue for HP Pavillion a6702f

Tags: motherboard, connector

I am replacing the MOBO on a [HP Pavillion a6702f](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/documentSubCategory?tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=ca&lang=en&product=3872323) and I have got to the point where the where the power button cable (white) needs to be attached as well as the cable for the card reader (black) on the front panel. The panel pins (white) are on the lower right corner beside the SATA connectors.

I have attached the image of the motherboard and the 2 connectors

[image: ASUS M4A785-M]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The black one is just a standard 10 pin usb connector, there should be a usb header on the the new motherboard.

The white one is proprietary HP, you would have to trace the wires to the from panel to see what function they perform, you may have to release the wires from the connector to attach them to the proper pins on the new mobo. It probably performs the function of switching the PC on, and possibly a hdd light and maybe a power on light.

HP does not release any data for these special connectors.

Comment: Unfortunately the closed hole on the black is on the opposite side and the white needs to be in singles to connect to the power-on light and hhd light

Comment: Are there any adaptor cords that exist?

Comment: Its tough, but the pins for power can be released with a tool or cut out of the connector. That is probably a non standard usb card reader, I would suggest replacing it with a standard one, unless you can figure out how to move the pins, which is risky, you could smoke the usb controller if you are wrong.

Comment: Adapter cords?, not that I have ever seen, its non standard HP engineering, for the power switch and lights, it is best to trace the wires back to the switch and whatever else they go to, can be a pain to do but is the only way I have ever found.

Answer (score 1):

I just replaced my motherboard with the ASUS.  It is working great!  I did have to purchase a different CPU fan as the ASUS requires a 4 pin plug instead of the standard 3 pin.  You can still use a 3 pin, but the fan runs at full RPM (~3650 RPM) and it is VERY loud.  I replaced it with a Rocketfish 11D03A (Universal CPU Fan and Heatsink) and it is back to normal as far as sound.

Now, regarding the connectors.  You can plug in the front panel audio to the motherboard.  There is a direct plug for that connector.  Next, you can plug in the USB panel to the motherboard as well.  Those are direct.  Now, there is a 5 pin (actually 4 pin) connector for the card reader.  I plugged that into the bottom 4 pin connector on another USB interface on the motherboard and it's working without issue.

The biggest issue was the black connector that you showed above.  I had to remove the wires from the connector. (very simple, just hold the lock up and pull the wire right out).

Then, I looked at the motherboard manual for the ASUS and plugged in each cable individually.

The breakdown is as follows:

```
Red/Red      = Power Button
Green/Blue   = Power LED
White/Yellow = HDD LED
```

Now I had to play with the LED wires as the `+/-` are not marked.  You'll know if they are reversed because the lights either won't work or they will not work as designed.  It was a quick fix and now my computer is completely back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  What I did was look at where the wire on the old motherboard wend HHd Pled and the Pwr wires.  Then I looked where they were connect on the 20 pin connector on theAsus motherboard.  I ordered a 16 pin connector model cbl0030 from technology Galaxy.  Took the pins out of the connections I needed and put them on the existing switch wires on my Hp then connected them to the asus board.  I hope this helps.

Jack